# How to config IE to make "wscript.shell" work

Tags: javascript

I have some code that used to work.  But I today when I try it again.  I kept got "[object error]".

I thought it's the problem of IE safety configure.  But I can find how to config IE to make it work.

```
function Run() {
  try   {
    var objShell = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
    objShell.Run("calc");
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must enable ActiveX:

- Click on *Tools*
- Select *Internet Options...*
- Select *Security* tab.
- Select Internet in Web content zone.
- Then, click on *Custom Level...*
- Go through all the ActiveX setting there, select *Prompt* or *Enable*

Answer (score 4):

it is Case Sensitive !!

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function OpenFile(){
alert ('Work');
var x = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
x.run('calc.exe');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input  type="button" value="GG"  href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenFile();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am trying to launch chrome in above it is not working why?


var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
ws.Exec("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");

Comment: @Ganesh : use / instead of \ and don't use spaces, for example : C:/Progra~1/Google/Chrome/Applic~1/chrome.exe

Comment: can this script can be run form CHROM BROWSER? actaully i am facing the issue to open a IE browser form CHROM using above script..

Comment: Anurag, we can't open IE from chrome browser with above script as chrome not supported ActiveXObject concept.

Answer (score 4):

It may be necessary to make a change to the IE settings:

For example, for the Local intranet zone, you typically need to change a custom setting to "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting."

I couldn't get the sample above to run without making the change.