# creating object "wscript.shell" fails

Tags: vbscript, wsh

My script looks like:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">        

Dim WshShell, oExec  
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("cmd /c cd D:\d & D: & winzip32.exe -min -a D:\a")

Do While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

WScript.Echo oExec.Status
</script>
```

The idea was to use explorer to open these files. The problem I'm having though is on the line:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

I keep getting the message

> ActiveX component can't create object: 'WScript.Shell'

I'm totally confused because this exact same code runs fine if I write it in
a `.htm` file.

Why does my browser treat my `.asp` page differently than the `.html` file?
How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Performing the following resolved the issue foe me.

Start --> Run --> Type "regsvr32.exe wshom.ocx" [without quotes] --> press enter.

Answer (score -2):

problem solved. need to enable few things in internet options - security-custom level- activx

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on how you fixed this issue? Since you haven't logged in here since June, 2010.... I'm guessing not.

Comment: Step-by-step directions over @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138002/how-to-config-ie-to-make-wscript-shell-work