# Running .BAT file in vbscript through Web Browser

Tags: html, vbscript

I am new to vbscript.I have no idea whether it happens or not.I got some VB script codes to run a batch file.

I am trying to run a *.bat* file in vbscript through HTML codes as:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test Button Events</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM NAME="Form1">
   <INPUT TYPE="Button" NAME="Button1" VALUE="Run">
   <SCRIPT FOR="Button1" EVENT="onClick" LANGUAGE="VBScript">
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "%comspec% /K C:\path\to\the\file\a.bat", 0
    ' 0 => hide
    MsgBox("File bop.txt successfully generated")
   </SCRIPT>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here, I want run the .bat file by clicking the *Run* button, which generates the bop.txt.
But it is not working.
What is the correct way to do this?

**Updates:**

Now I am able to run the a.bat file by replacing the path as:

```
file:///C:/path/to/the/file/a.bat
```

But its not generating the file bop.txt.

a.bat contains:

```
@echo off
echo Hello World!>bop.txt
```

Comment: This sort of thing might have worked in 1999 versions of InternetExploder, but I'm reasonably sure modern browsers will block this.

Comment: @Incognito-Why this thing are blocked by modern browser? Does it cause any security issue? Is it not a good practice ? I am trying to implement these things in an application.Should I proceed with it or is there any other way ?

Comment: Unless you're dealing with some special MSIE/LDAP stuff I've scrubbed from my mind, it's a bad idea and not cross-platform. JavaScript is probably want you want to be using for websites that need client side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could be the right place to start - Internet Settings > Security > Custom level > Active x

You might have to enable some Activex Permission.

[creating object "wscript.shell" fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521655/problem-creating-object-wscript-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are using this, I've had success using .hta files, so something like:

```
<JOB ID="Test">
    <Head>
        <HTA:APPLICATION
        ID="Test"
        />

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
        Sub buttonClick
                Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "%comspec% /K C:\path\to\the\file\a.bat", 0
            ' 0 => hide
            MsgBox("File bop.txt successfully generated")
        End Sub
        </SCRIPT>

    </HEAD>
    <HTML>
        <FORM NAME="Form1">
        <INPUT TYPE="Button" NAME="Button1" VALUE="Run" ONCLICK="buttonClick">
    </HTML>
</JOB>
```

Save as file.hta

HTA files have more scope security-wise as far as I understand so are not blocked by the browser.

There's more information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496(v=vs.85).aspx