# Why WScript doesn't works?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, shell, wsh

If I try it in IE9 (win7), then it works perfectly, but when I try to run this code in IE8,7,6 (winXP) the debugger writes, that can't create the object.

```
var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
```

If you have any idea, then please share it with me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the complete error?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138002/how-to-config-ie-to-make-wscript-shell-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely an error with the security settings in your Windows XP test machine. Accessing  WScript is a highly protected action because it exposes your computer essentially to complete takeover. What you're seeing isn't a difference between a version of IE, but a difference between either the OS (Win7 -> WinXP) or more likely the configuration setup between the two.

Make sure ActiveX is setup correctly: [How to config IE to make "wscript.shell" work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138002/how-to-config-ie-to-make-wscript-shell-work) (by "correctly" I mean "with security disabled" which most people would say is changing it to be incorrect).