# Javascript Wscript.Shell command not working by clicking button in browser

Tags: javascript, html, wsh

I am using this code: to create new folder by clicking a button in browser,

```
function exer()
{

    var wsr = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    wsr.Exec("cmd /C mkdir C:\\users\\vakav\\Desktop\\VBSCRIPT_2013\\new");

}
<body>
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="exer()" />
</body>
```

Its not working but if i run the above function in a test.js file and run the following commnad, its working: cmd> cscript.exe test.js  Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

WScript only works on IE, and you must install ActiveX.
Follow this thread : [How to config IE to make "wscript.shell" work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138002/how-to-config-ie-to-make-wscript-shell-work)