# JS: Read registry values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read registry values in javascript, below is wat i got to do, but ended up with an error `Automation server can't create object`.
I'm getting above error for my first line.

```
 //Code
    var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var value = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\CompName\\ServerUrl");
```

Am i doing wrong??
Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to config IE to make "wscript.shell" work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138002/how-to-config-ie-to-make-wscript-shell-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you've not enabled Active X in the broswer security settings.

In IE9:

a) Go to Tools-->Internet Options

b) Select security tab

c) Click on Trusted Sites (or Local Intranet depending on whether your site is trusted or not)

d) Click on Custom Level

e) Ensure that "Initialize and script active x controls is not marked safe for scripting" is enabled.