# Getting the error 'wscript is undefind' when using activex

Tags: asp.net, activex

I want to get the client computer name in my web application. My web application is going to run on IE and I am trying  activex for this.

I have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function UseActiveX() {

      var wsh = new ActiveXObject(wscript.network)
      var strCompName = wsh.computername;
      alert(strCompName);
  }</script>
```

but I got the error 'wscript is undefind'. Can anybody tell why this happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to config IE to make "wscript.shell" work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138002/how-to-config-ie-to-make-wscript-shell-work)

Comment: i read that and did as in that.. but still its not working...anything i missed or do i need to install anything..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's just a typo error.

**wscript** spells with an **uppercase W and uppercase S** + needs to be between quotes

**computername** spells with **uppercase C and uppercase N**

Try this :

> var wsh = new ActiveXObject('**WS**cript.network')
>
> var strCompName = wsh.**C**omputer**N**ame;